# How can I stop onload event?

Tags: jquery

I am using Ajax and jQuery to get output on click event of submit button

I have two files

1. `Index.php` (contains the jQuery & Ajax Code)
2. `actionfile.php` (A php file that extracts the data sent by Ajax code in `Index.php` and stores the data in a file)

Index.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" value="121212"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<script> 
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var txt =document.getElementById('txt1').value;  //textbox value
    alert(txt);
    var txt1 = "txt1="+txt;
    alert(txt1);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "actionfile.php",
            data:txt1,
            success: function() {
               alert("success");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And actionfile.php:

```php
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $map=$_POST['txt1'];
    $fp=fopen("file.txt","w");
    fwrite($fp,$map);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

The problem is, if I remove the piece of code `$("#submit").click(function()` ajax works fine, meaning it submits data when the page is loaded (provided I give default value in textbox). When I keep the code `$("#submit").click(function()` intact, the function is called only when submit button is pressed but in this case AJAX fails.

The code is available on http://www.code.guru99.com/kishore

What is causing this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "AJAX Fails"? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var txt =document.getElementById('txt1').value;  //textbox value
        alert(txt);
        var txt1 = "txt1="+txt;
        alert(txt1);
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "actionfile.php",
                data:txt1,
                success: function() {
                   alert("success");

                   //here you can simulate click submit
                }
            });
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type form `submit` to `button`:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
```

Comment: AFAIK,Button Inside form is acts like submit button.

Comment: @Baadshah Who told that? you can try yourself. Just change the the type on the above link and try it :)

Comment: @Baadshah: `type="button"` will *not* submit the form.  `type="submit"` will.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this:

Change submit into button.

```
      <form name="myform" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" value="121212"/>
      <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="test();" />


<script> 
       function test()
 { 
var txt =document.getElementById('txt1').value;  //textbox value
alert(txt);
var txt1 = "txt1="+txt;
alert(txt1);
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actionfile.php",
        data:txt1,
        success: function() {
           alert("success");
        }
    });
 }
</script>
```

hope this will give you some solution.

Comment: Why would you replace a bound event handler with an inline one?

Comment: @Rocket check this it will give the exact output.

Comment: Yeah, I know it will.  But this is bad practice and still won't solve his issue.

Comment: I didn't.  I don't like inline event handlers, but I didn't down-vote.

Comment: @rocket its okay buddy. anyway i have learned some stuff from you. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when you remove the `$("#submit").click(function()` because your `<form>` is posted and the data is sent.

To have AJAX submit the data, you need to use `type="button"`, or change your event to:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```